# Tensorboard graph orphan layers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

While building a model that includes transfer learning (from VGG-16).
I encounter this strange behavior. Tensorboard graph shows the layers which are not part of the new model but part of the old, above the point of seperation, and they are just dangling there.

[image]

---

When investigating further, `model.summary()` does not show these layers, `model.get_layer("block4_conv1")` can't find them either, and the keras `tf.keras.utils.plot_model` doesn't show them too. but if they are not part of the graph, how would tensorboard know about them?

To build the new model, I used the recommended method.

Model first stage:

```
    vgg_input_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=x)
    final_vgg_kayer = vgg_input_model.get_layer("block3_pool")
    input_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=vgg_input_model.inputs, outputs=final_vgg_kayer.output)
    input_model.trainable = True

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 1, padding="same", activation='relu', name="stage0_final_conv1")(input_model.output)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 1, padding="same", activation='relu', name="stage0_final_conv2")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 1, padding="same", activation='relu', name="stage0_final_conv3")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 1, padding="same", activation='relu', name="stage0_final_conv4")(x)
```

---

```
TF:2.1 (nightly-2.x)
PY:3.5
Tensorboard: 2.1.0a20191124
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple methods, I came to the conclusion that the recommended way is wrong. doing `model_b=tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_a.inputs,outputs=model_a.get_layet("some_layer").output)` will lead to dangling layers from `model_a`.
Using `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` in between may cleans the keras graph, but tensorboard's graph is left empty then.

The best solution I found is config+weights copy of the required model, layer by layer.
And rebuilding the connections in a new model. that way there is no relationship whatsoever in the Keras graph between the two models.
(*This is simple for a sequential model like VGG, but might be more difficult for something like ResNet*)

---

Sample code:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

input_shape = (368, 368, 3)  #only the input shape is shared between the models
#transfer learning model definition
input_layer_vgg = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
vgg_input_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_layer_vgg)
name_last_layer = "block3_pool" #the last layer to copy

tf.keras.backend.clear_session() #clean the graph from the transfer learning model

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape) #define the input layer for the first model
x=input_layer
for layer in vgg_input_model.layers[1:]:    #copy over layers, without the other input layer
    config=layer.get_config()  #get config
    weights=layer.get_weights() #get weights
    #print(config)
    copy_layer=type(layer).from_config(config) #create the new layer from config
    x=copy_layer(x) #connect to previous layers,
                    #required for the proper sizing of the layer,
                    #set_weights will not work without it
    copy_layer.set_weights(weights)    

    if layer.name == name_last_layer:
        break
del vgg_input_model

input_model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=x) #create the new model,
                                                        #if needed x can be used further doen the line
```